# jQuery buttons to show/hide classes IF classes exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle, show-hide

...apologies in advance for my bastardized coding, I'm still toying with this.  In short, I'm trying to have 3 (maybe more in future) buttons that, when individually clicked, show all divs with a specific .class name (while hiding other divs with other specific .class names).  Something like a fake content-toggle system.

```
$("#mr-button-01").click(function() {
  $(".key-01").css({ "background":"#ff00ff" }).animate( "slow" );
  $(".key-02, .key-03").removeAttr('style');
  $(".info-01").show();
  $(".info-02, .info-03").hide();
return false;
});
```

Now, **mr-button-01** and **key-01** are the same element (just id and class for styling).  This code is repeated for every different button, simply shutting down or focusing on the *other* "**info**" classes.  Probably not the best plan of action, but each button does something different and has a different 'activated' .css style, so I dunno how else to handle that yet.

Original point: I'm trying to figure out how to check if "**.info-01**" even exists on the page.  If it doesn't, we keep, but kill the toggle button all together.  Something like...

```
if
  .info-01 DOES exist
  proceed with original ridiculous 'click sorting' thing
else
  .info-01 DOESN'T exist on the page
  .#mr-button-01 click does nothing
  .key-01 (aka #mr-button-01) has a "dead" .css style applied to it
```

I understand there's '**:not**', and a few other options - I'm just not clear on the syntax or the best way to handle this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, and feel free to suggest an alternate method, a more concise way of doing this to remove bloat, etc.

HTML, very basic:

```
<div id="nigga">
  <a href="#" id="mr-button-01"><div class="key-01">Choice 01</div></a>
  <a href="#" id="mr-button-02"><div class="key-02">Choice 02</div></a>
  <a href="#" id="mr-button-03"><div class="key-03">Choice 03</div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: So this is the first time I've ever been offended by a  spectacularly poor, even if 'ironic,' choice of an attribute-value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is you are looking for:

```
$("#mr-button-01").click(function(){
    // Check if element with searched class exists
    if($('.info-01')){
        //Apply css to clicked button
        $(this).animate({'background-color', 'ff00ff'), 'slow', function(){
            //Open info-1
            $(".info-01").show();
            //Hide info-02 and info-03 if they are shown
            $(".info-02").hide();
            $(".info-03").hide();
        });
    }else{
        //If searched class doe's not exist
        $(this).addClass('dead css class name');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work, still digging at it.

Comment: it's very basic:

<div id="nigga">
<a href="#" id="mr-button-01"><div class="key-01">Choice 01</div></a>
<a href="#" id="mr-button-02"><div class="key-02">Choice 02</div></a>
<a href="#" id="mr-button-03"><div class="key-03">Choice 03</div></a>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Your html and js dont seem too compatible, perhaps try something more along the lines of:

```
<a href="#" class="mr-button" data-id="1"><div class="key key-1">Choice 01</div></a>
<a href="#" class="mr-button" data-id="2"><div class="key key-2">Choice 02</div></a>
<a href="#" class="mr-button" data-id="3"><div class="key key-3">Choice 03</div></a>
```

and

```
$(".mr-button").click(function() {
  $key = $(".key-" + $(this).attr("data-id")); // locate key using this data-id
  if($key.length != 0){ // if $key exists, do silly thangs
    $key.show();
    $(".key").hide();
  }
  return false;
});
```

It's a wee bit more html, but it's more reusable code.

Comment: thanks - this seems like a solid direction, imma reboot my brain and handle this later